# Use shell variable substitution with current filepath

Tags: command-line, external-command, bash

I want to be able to easily change the filename. This works:

```
:! var=%; mv % ${var/.txt/.asc}
```

But this doesn't:

```
:! mv % ${%/.txt/.asc}
```

My questions:

- Why doesn't this work? Doesn't VIM simply replace `%` with the current filepath?
- How can I use shell variable substitution with the current filename (in a more elegant way than the first I proposed).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Why doesn't this work?

This doesn't work for exactly why you say, vim is replacing the % with the path.

So, your non working line

```
:! mv % ${%/.txt/.asc}
```

is expanding to

```
:! mv myfile.txt ${myfile.txt/.txt/.asc}
```

which bash will call a bad substitution; You are trying to expand a variable called myfile.txt, and bash doesn't support variable names with . in them (and the . may mean something else).

### How can I do shell substitution?

After a quick search, I could find no way to do substitutions without first assigning a value to a shell variable and operating on the variable itself.

Not what you asked, but you could achieve similar results using Vim's filename-modifiers (`:help filename-modifiers`) like so:

```
:! mv % %:r.asc
```

The `:r` after the % removes the last extension, and then we append `.asc` to it. The downside is that, if the extension wasn't .txt, we're still replacing it with .asc, but maybe that's what you want anyway.

Another example:

```
:! mv % %:s?.txt?.asc?
```

Which does exactly like your bash example, I think, and has the bonus of giving you the full power of Vim's substitute command on the filename. Here the :s modifier invokes substitute logic just like the `:s` ex command. Their example uses `?` as the separation character instead of `/` because you are more likely to use `/` in file paths than `?`.

The only thing you don't get are flags after the substituted text bit. Since the most likely flag you'd want is `g` (to match all occurrences on this "line"), you can use `:gs?pat?sub?` instead of `:s?pat?sub?`