# how to use variables in vimscript shell commands

Tags: vimscript, filesystem

I have this code intended to:

1. read current line
2. extract variable from end of line, looking for text like `#ad04e482`
3. search for filename that begins with the string `ad04e482`
4. open that file to edit in vim
5. bind this to a few keystrokes `<leader>tn`

I'm struggling to define and use these variables inside the `execute` function calls...

```
function TaskSearch()
  let line = getline('.')
  let task_id = split(line, "#")[1]
  let task_note = execute('find ~/.task/notes/ -name "task_id*"')
  execute('edit ~/.task/notes/$task_note')
endfunction
command! TaskSearch :call TaskSearch()
nnoremap <leader>tn :TaskSearch <Enter>
```

I've tried many different variatlions of the `let task_note...` and `execute(...)` statements without any success.

I've looked through [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948024/using-variables-in-a-vim-shell-command) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979801/saving-return-value-of-execute-function-into-variable-vimscript) [on](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22089/how-to-get-put-the-result-of-a-shell-command-in-a-variable) [the](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6705/use-shell-variable-substitution-with-current-filepath) [stack](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22334/system-cant-get-output-of-shell-command-in-vimrc) [network](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/extract-the-result-of-a-shell-command-to-a-variable-in-a-vimrc-file) but I haven't seen any examples using a vimscript variable (like `task_id` in my case) inside a shell command's arguments.

I need to take the results of that command, which should be just a single file, and then open that file in a new buffer to edit it.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Highly related](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21392/10604)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way that works...

```
function! TaskSearch()
  ..snip...
  let task_note = system('find ~/.task/notes -name "' . task_id . '"\*')
  exe 'e ' . task_note
endfunction
```

Call with `:call TaskSearch()`.

Some of the key changes...

1. Escaping of glob (`*`) in the `find` call.
2. Use of `system()` which is a vim function that returns result of executing external processes.
3. Use of Ex commands rather than function(s) to open the file, i.e. using `exe` and `e[dit]`.
4. `find` should return a full path so there shouldn't be a need to repeat `~/.task/notes` in the `exe` line.

Might need a little fine tuning to get it to work for your exact problem (e.g. this isn't controlling for a scenario where `find` returns more than one file...make sure your query is specific/explicit enough to prevent that or use additional shell commands to narrow it down, if needed). Let me know if you have any problems or questions about how it works.

An important point is that when you want to include the value of a variable in a command you usually need to use something like `exe`, i.e. something that will treat its arguments as an expression to be evaluated.

Comment: that works, thank you!  Now I realize I had the wrong approach because sometimes the file does not exist yet.... so my lines now look like `let task_note = system('task ' . task_id . ' | grep UUID | sed "s/UUID          //"')` and `exe 'e ' . '~/.task/notes/' . task_note . '\.mkd'` which gives me the error: `Error detected while processing function TaskSearch:
line    5:
E16: Invalid range: 59d8fd85-f117-49c3-a14a-4474af492825^@\.mkd`

Comment: It opens a buffer `2 %a   "~/.task/notes/No command specified - assuming 'information'." line 1`

Comment: Instead of using find, I want to get the full id of the task like `task ad04e482 | grep UUID | sed 's/UUID          //'`.  That way I can open `ad04e482-5ec2-4c34-a03f-b39344b99ef4.mkd` whether or not it exists already; if it doesn't exist I want to create a new file with that name.

Comment: Is my explanation of that in the first two comments clear/readable?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do with your shell command but the `system()` call looks syntactically correct. Just print the result before trying to open it until you are sure it's correct. Then you could do this:  `exe printf("e ~/.task/notes/%s.mkd", task_note)`

Comment: `printf("e ~/.task/notes/%s.mkd", task_note)` still gives me the same error.

Comment: Sorry... I was guessing that printing it would be achieved by that command you posted.  I don't know how to print something from vimscript.  The shell command works from the shell commandline, invoking `task` and then filtering the output to get the long string of UUID.

Comment: When you say to print... do you mean vimscript function will print a line to vim inside the buffer I have open?

Comment: oh sweet!  it does so... but it returns the expected results on the second line of output, the first line of output contains the problematic string `No command specified - assuming 'information'.`  Do you have any idea what that means?

Comment: No that must be from `task`...whatever that is.

Comment: Oh you're right!  So the final (I think!) issue now is that my attempt to add the `.mkd` extension to filename isn't working in `exe 'e ' . '~/.task/notes/' . task_note . '.mkd'` it says `E492: Not an editor command: .mkd` and opens the file w/o the extension.  Can you tell me what I need to do to append `.mkd` onto the `task_note` filename?

Comment: I already did. `exe printf(....`

Comment: `exe printf("e ~/.task/notes/%s.mkd", task_note)` still gives me `E492: Not an editor command: .mkd` ...and then I hit <enter> and it opens the file without the "mkd" extension.

Comment: The command is fine. Maybe you have some garbage in `task_note` like escape characters or something. Or a NEWLINE.

Comment: yes!  it was a newline character.  Adding ` | tr -d "\n"` to the `system()` call makes it work!

Comment: Thank you so much <3

Comment: Cool. You're welcome.